# iOS send multiple push notifications

Tags: php, mysql, ios, notifications, push

i want to send with a php script multiple PN from an database. In the table are 3 device token, but the script only send it to the first one.

here the script, has someone an idea.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'DEV.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp){
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
}

$ausgabe.= 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL . '<hr>';

$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'note.wav',
    'badge' => 1
);

$payload = json_encode($body);

$selectSQL = 'SELECT * from app_pushnotification';
$result = mysql_query($selectSQL);  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $i+=1;
    $ausgabe.= $i.' - '. $row['device_token'].' ';
    $deviceToken = $row['device_token'];

    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$result){
        $ausgabe.='Message to not delivered' . PHP_EOL . '<hr>';
    } else {
        $ausgabe.='Message to successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL . '<hr>';
    }

}

$ausgabe.='close connection';
fclose($fp);

} 
echo $ausgabe;
```

Greets Kevin

Comment: Try using one connection per message. Close/Open the connection in the loop.

Comment: @kdogisthebest that's a bad idea. too slow!

Comment: Kevin, how many rows does the query return? Are you sure the error is not with the database, rather than with the APNS server?

Comment: the databse returns all 3 tokens, if i dont send the message

Comment: Does it output "Message to successfully delivered" for all 3?

Comment: no, when i will send the message it gives me 1 line: but when i decomment thedrite line i got all 3 lines.

Comment: i have seen that i get a PHP warning, but dont know what to do. mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, integer given

Comment: i have found a solution, i save the tokens from database in a array. in a for loop i send the messages, that works. Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that you change the value of `$result` in the loop. Therefore the script couldn't fetch the next row array.

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'DEV.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp){
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
}

$ausgabe.= 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL . '<hr>';

$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'note.wav',
    'badge' => 1
);

$payload = json_encode($body);

$selectSQL = 'SELECT * from app_pushnotification';
$result = mysql_query($selectSQL);  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $i+=1;
    $ausgabe.= $i.' - '. $row['device_token'].' ';
    $deviceToken = $row['device_token'];

    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    $write_result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    if (!$write_result){
        $ausgabe.='Message to not delivered' . PHP_EOL . '<hr>';
    } else {
        $ausgabe.='Message to successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL . '<hr>';
    }

}

$ausgabe.='close connection';
fclose($fp);

} 
echo $ausgabe;
```

Note that the second `$result =` is now `$write_result =`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create daemon/cronjob to send push notifications. It will help you to send asynchronous and multiple messages without UI freeze. Ref link : http://kvz.io/blog/2009/01/09/create-daemons-in-php/